# Cannot Center Popover Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uipopovercontroller

I am trying to make a popover that will allow users to swipe between images (is there a better approach to this than using a popover?).

Right now to make the popover, I have spend hours googling on simply how to make a rectangle center in the screen. From the internet my code is:

```
    // get a reference to the view controller for the popover
    let popController = UIStoryboard(name: "Event", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "carouselPopover")

    // set the presentation style
    popController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.popover

    let width = view.frame.width
    popController.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: width, height: 300)
    // set up the popover presentation controller
    popController.popoverPresentationController?.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirection.up
    popController.popoverPresentationController?.delegate = self
    popController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view
    popController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = CGRect(x: view.bounds.midX, y: view.bounds.midY, width: 0, height: 0)
    popController.popoverPresentationController?.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirection(rawValue: 0)

    // present the popover
    self.present(popController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

However, for the life of me I cannot understand why the popover is not centered[image]

It only loses its center when I set the popController's preferred content size. Any thoughts?

TL:DR
I want to 1) center the popover on the screen, 2) Make the popover 1:1 ratio, and 3) make the width of the popover proportional to the width of the parent screen. How can I do that without 1000's lines of code.

Comment: What is - `let width = view.frame.width` prints out?

What is view and what is frame?

Why not use auto layout?

Complete your question according to rules, its lack of information

Comment: How can I used autolayout with popover? The frame width is the width of the parent frame calling the popover.

Comment: Why not use UICollectionView with `Scroll DIrection = Horizontal` and `Paging Enabled`. With paging enabled it will always be in the center.

Comment: again, I am not asking about the scrolling, I am asking about how to center the popover.

Comment: @AlexKornhauser i dont know about popover mechanics, but you can simply achieve behaviour you need with custom view and default animations.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom popover class. Then you establish delegate patterns to determine if user swipes.

```
protocol PopoverDelegate: class {
  func imageviewDidSwipe(_ popover: Popover)
}

class Popover: UIView {

weak var delegate: PopoverDelegate?

  init(frame: CGRect) {
   super.init(frame: frame)
   backgroundColor = UIColor.white
  }

  func setupImage(_ image: UIImage) {
    let imageView = UIView(frame: CGRect.zero)
    imageView.image = image
    self.addSubview(imageView)

    imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    imageView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    imageView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    imageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true // However big you want
    imageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true // However big you want
  }

  func showPopover(over view: UIView) {
    view.addSubview(self)
    translatesAutoResizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    centerXAnchor.contraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: frame.height).isActive = true
    widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: frame.width).isActive = true
 }

}
```

To use...

```
class vC: UIViewController {

  func ImageOnClick() {
   // change view to where you want popover to show on top of
   let popover = Popover(frame: view.frame)
   popover.setupImage(image.png)
   popover.delegate = self
   showPopover(over: view)
  }

}

extension vC: PopoverDelegate {
  func imageviewDidSwipe(_ popover: Popover) {
    // image swiped
  }
}
```

Comment: Forget about the swiping for a second, I'm using an external library. I would like to 1) center the popover, 2) make the layout 1:1, and 3) make the layout relative to the width of the screen.

Comment: The UIPopoverController class is deprecated, so i would suggest making a customclass. Sorry i cant answer these questions at the moment i am away from computer.